# IndexOutOfRangeException when Publishing on Reactive Stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I am developing an application that uses a connectable observable for publishing results.
These results are consumed by two observers on two different threads; one observable run on the UI thread and displays the results in a table and a chart, while the other observable runs on the default thread pool sends the results to a REST end point.

However, in certain situations after a variable time an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown.
I suspect this is because of a concurrency issue with my thread that sends the results to the REST web service.
If I do not start this thread, the results are displayed just fine.
Furthermore, the irregularity of the occurrence is typical for a concurrency issue.
I attached the exception's stack trace.

```
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
at System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Buffer`1.CountExact.ExactSink.OnNext(TSource value)
at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1.OnNext(T value)
at System.Reactive.Sink`1.ForwardOnNext(TTarget value)
at System.Reactive.IdentitySink`1.OnNext(T value)
at System.Reactive.AutoDetachObserver`1.OnNextCore(T value)
at System.Reactive.ObserverBase`1.OnNext(T value)
at Wetr.Simulator.viewModel.SimulationViewModel.OnSimulationResultPublished(SimulationResult measurement) in E:\programming\csharp\Weatr\Wetr.Simulator\Wetr.Simulator\viewModel\SimulationViewModel.cs:Line 96.
```

The code for publishing results is shown below.

```
private void OnSimulationResultPublished(SimulationResult measurement)
{
    this.aggregatedSimulationResultObserver?.OnNext(measurement);
}
```

The measurement writer uses the following code to subscribe to events.

```
this.measurementStreamSubscription = measurementStream
    .Buffer(BUFFER_SIZE)
    .Subscribe(
        results => this.writer.AddMeasurementsAsync(
            results
                .Where(container => container != null)
                .Select(container => container.Result)
        )
    );
```

UI updates are processed by the subscription shown below.

```
this.uiUpdateSubscription =
    this.AggregatedSimulationResults
        //.Select(result => new SimulationResult(
        //    result.Station, result.MeasurementSequenceID,
        //    new Measurement(
        //        result.Result.Station,
        //        result.Result.MeasurementType,
        //        new DateTime(result.Result.Timestamp.Ticks),
        //        result.Result.MeasuredValue
        //    )
        //))
        .ObserveOn(DispatcherScheduler.Current)
        .Subscribe(this.DisplayNewSimulationResults);
```

I have read through [Intro to RX](http://introtorx.com), but I am still fairly new to the Reactive Extensions.
I have also tried creating new copies of the measurements before buffering them, but this hasn't fixed the issue.
Therefore, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is `AddMeasurementsAsync` an async method returning a `Task`? If so then this could be a problem because you are not awaiting it in the call to `Subscribe`.

Comment: Yes, it is an asynchronous method. I am now awaiting the call to `AddMeasurementAsync`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Dirk Can you please post your comment as answer? It is much more stable now, although I am going to do some additional testing.

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant to write an answer, because I'm not very familiar with RX. I also don't know whether simply awaiting the method will work perfectly. A quick search turned up https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/459, which might be of interest to you.